# Tao OpenGL (mouse using Tao.freeglut.dll)

Tags: visual-studio, opengl, windows-7, tao-framework

I am using the code from 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/OpenGLNavigation2TaoCShar.aspx

and trying it to run in Visual Studio C# 2008 Pro Ed installed on Windows 7 64bit

Whenever I run the code it stops abruptly and says the following

"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"

Please advice what to do

Answer (score 0):

In your project properties, under "Build," try setting your platform target to x86. IIRC, the Tao libraries load 32-bit versions of the OpenGL libraries, and thus will only work in 32-bit projects.